# How to show a message when no results are found

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I adapt this code to show a `<div>No Results Found</div>` on the page when no results are found?

I've got this simple image gallery with an input to filter results based on the contents of the `data-filter` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Filter" id="filter">
<div class="results-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail" data-filter="Apple">image</div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail" data-filter="Orange">image</div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail" data-filter="Banana">image</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery:

```
$("#filter").keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".gallery-thumbnail").filter(function() {
        $(this).toggle($(this).attr("data-filter").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the same method and do it like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#filter").keyup( function(){
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".gallery-thumbnail").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).attr("data-filter").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        });
        $('.noresult').toggle($(".gallery-thumbnail:visible").length == 0)
    });
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#filter").keyup( function(){
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $(".gallery-thumbnail").filter(function() {
            $(this).toggle($(this).attr("data-filter").toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
        });
        $('.noresult').toggle($(".gallery-thumbnail:visible").length == 0)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="filter" placeholder="Filter" id="filter">
<div class="results-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail" data-filter="Apple">image</div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail" data-filter="Orange">image</div>
    <div class="gallery-thumbnail" data-filter="Banana">image</div>
    <div class="noresult" style="display:none">No Results Found</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You put 'No Results' div on the page, with a class which initially defaults it to be hidden (`display:none`). If your filter returns no results, you add a class to the div to show it (`display: block`). When the filter is cleared, and you have results again, you remove the 'show' class, reverting it back to it's default 'hidden' state.